# Vue JS push items to array?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to push the input to the array. When I press the button to add the items nothing happens. I've searched multiple websites but it seems that I am too dumb to find the right code :(
Do anyone know whats the problem with the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Clientseitige Webentwicklung mit Vue.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app_basic">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="value in cars">{{ value }}</li>
        </ul>
        <input id="input1" type="text" v-model="newFarbe" placeholder="farbe">
        <input id="input2" type="text" v-model="newMarke" placeholder="marke">
        <input id="input3" type="text" v-model="newPS" placeholder="ps">
        <button v-on:click="addCar">Hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app_basic= new Vue(
        {
            el: '#app_basic',
            data: {
               cars:{
                farbe: 'Blau',
                marke: 'Ford',
                ps: '240'
               }
            
            },
            methods:{
                addCar: function() {
               this.cars.push({farbe : this.newFarbe, marke : this.newMarke, ps : this.newPS});
               this.newFarbe=''; 
               this.newMarke=''; 
               this.newPS=''; 
                }
            }
        });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is newFarbe?

Comment: it should be the input from input1

Comment: There are two problems with your code: a) `cars` is not an array so it doesn't have a `.push` method. b) `newFarbe`, `newMarke` and `newPs` are not defined in `data`, therefore not reactive, therefore not linked to your model (in other words, they are always `undefined` in your component's model - vue is not informed about their changes). The answer provided fixes both, although it doesn't call each one out individually.

Comment: Another minor improvement would be naming. There's no point in prefixing all props with `new`. Here's what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/v2wrmbc8/. You also don't need `id`s on inputs (you don't have labels to target them, so...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cars` should be an `array` and the inputs models should be defined in `data`. Moreover, it's better to have some sort of validation before the insertion:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app_basic',
  data: {
    cars: [
      {
        farbe: 'Blau',
        marke: 'Ford',
        ps: '240'
      }
    ],
    newFarbe: '',
    newMarke: '',
    newPS: ''
  },
  methods:{
    addCar: function() {
      if(!this.newFarbe || !this.newMarke || this.newPS) return;
      this.cars.push({
        farbe : this.newFarbe, marke : this.newMarke, ps : this.newPS
      });
      this.newFarbe=''; 
      this.newMarke=''; 
      this.newPS=''; 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app_basic">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="value in cars">
      {{ value.farbe }} -
      {{ value.marke }} -
      {{ value.ps }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input id="input1" type="text" v-model="newFarbe" placeholder="farbe">
  <input id="input2" type="text" v-model="newMarke" placeholder="marke">
  <input id="input3" type="text" v-model="newPS" placeholder="ps">
  <button v-on:click="addCar">Hinzufügen</button>
</div>
```